# Why is my method returning a null object reference in my Espresso Test?

Tags: android, realm, android-espresso, android-testing

I am new to Android Testing and using Espresso. I am trying to test that when the user clicks on an item in the RecyclerView, the correct data is shown. However, I am getting a null object reference when I try to run my test. Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

MyActivity.class

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

        cakeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CakeViewModel.class);
        if (cakeViewModel.cake.getValue() != null) {
            cakeViewModel.cake.setValue(null);
        }
        retrieveData();
    }

    private void retrieveData() {

        cakeViewModel.cake.setValue(null);
        mainDb = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        Intent recipeIntent = getIntent();
        int cakeId = recipeIntent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.CAKE_ID, 0);
        Cake cake = mainDb.where(Cake.class).equalTo("id", cakeId).findFirst();
        cakeViewModel.cake.setValue(cake);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(cake.getName());
    }
```

My Test:

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class RecipeActivityUITest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<RecipeActivity> recipeActivityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(RecipeActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void clickOnRecyclerViewItem_opensRecipeStepActivity() {

        onView(withId(R.id.rv_step_list)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.rv_step_list)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click()));
        onView(withId(R.id.vp_step)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.ciaransloan.bakingapp.api.model.Cake.getName()' on a null object reference
at com.ciaransloan.bakingapp.RecipeActivity.retrieveData(RecipeActivity.java:108)
at com.ciaransloan.bakingapp.RecipeActivity.onCreate(RecipeActivity.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my issue was that I was not passing any intent in my test so when it tried to load the Object, it was not retrieving the ID from the intent. The issue was not to do with my database after all. To resolve, I changed the @Rule in my Test to the following:

```java
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<RecipeActivity> recipeActivityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<RecipeActivity>(RecipeActivity.class) {
        @Override
        protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
            return new Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), RecipeActivity.class).putExtra(MainActivity.CAKE_ID, 1);
        }
    };
```